# How does "etw. an sich reißen" compare to "sich etw. unter den Nagel reißen"?

Tags: difference

In conversation, I said jokingly:

> Er muss uns reingelegt und **sich** die Beute selbst **unter den Nagel gerissen** haben!

In hindsight, I'm wondering how using "etw. an sich reißen" might have been nuanced. Does "sich etw. unter den Nagel reißen" carry a more pejorative connotation?

Comment: *reißen* hat bzw hatte unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. Vgl das reißen einer Beute oder das reißen am Reißbrett, letzteres verwandt mit *write*. Ich möchte nicht fug und fest behaupten, *sich etwas zuschreiben* hätte die Bedeutung *aneignen*, doch selbst bei *das Steuer an sich reißen* fehlt die physikalische Komponente (ie. there's no denotional semantics). Grimm betont *reißen* gehe sonst auf *aufreißen* auch im Sinne *pflügen* zurück (vgl *zer-rüttet* aber auch *rütteln*, *rattern*, *retten*), daher würde ich *die Grenzen neu ziehen* unterstellen. Während *Nagel* an der Wurzel eh schwierig ist

Comment: Obwohl *das Steuer an sich reißen* bei Seegang auch einfach *fest halten, mit vollem Körpereinsatz* bedeuten mag.

Comment: In the context of your example, *unter den Nagel gerissen* is indeed the better (more idiomatic) phrase than *an sich gerissen*, so you said it well.

Answer (score 2):

Sich etwas unter den Nagel reißen is more colloquial, and has a slightly more aggressive connotation because it implies stronger that the person had greedy motivations.

Answer (score 2):

It is interchangeable.

My core nuance is that:

- an sich reißen = you gain power over sth./ you possess sth. now
- etwas unter den Nagel reißen = you own sth. now

Thus, the first might come with the latter: if you gain power over an object (de jure: possession (Besitz)), it might also be yours (de jure: property/ownership (Eigentum)) [now].

As already known: In both cases it was not yours and - at least for bystanders - it looks like the one changing of ownership/ possession took the other(s) by surprise/ cought them unaware of the situation/ opportunities. If it is or feels unfair depends on circumstances and point of view.

That means, that if anybody else would have had the same thoughts and overview of the situation, they would "simultanously run for the thing to gather". Just some realize it to late/ don't have capacities to do (like to less money to buy, less uncaring to take advantage).

My distinction in usage:

- an sich reißen: I use that more for taking the power that comes with a job/function/authority role
- unter den Nagel reißen: I use that more for taking objects

DWDS has examples for "[an sich reißen](https://www.dwds.de/r?from=&q=an%20sich%20rei%C3%9Fen&h=1&corpus=kern)" - and most refer to positions/ jobs:

- Kommando an sich gerissen (~ took command)
- die Präsidentschaft an sich riß (~ took presidency)

In wiktionary are examples for "[unter den Nagel reißen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sich_etwas_unter_den_Nagel_rei%C3%9Fen)" - and all refer to objects, not positions/ jobs:

- die teure Uhr unter den Nagel reißen (~ being the first one to take watch)
- Anbauflächen unter den Nagel reißen (~ being the first buyer for the agriculture area)

Comment: Unfairness ist m.E. sehr selten im Spiel, Überrumpelung schon. Es ist viel mehr sehr rasches Handeln bei einer sich bietenden Gelegenheit, wie wenn die Katze sich eine Maus unter den Nagel reisst, das ist auch nicht unfair gegenüber den anderen Katzen.

Comment: There is significant overlap, but not intercvangeable, i.e. in Q's example sentence.

Comment: @user-unknown wenn ein Wolf [sich] ein Schaf [unter den Nagel] reißt, ist das auch nicht unfair gegenüber dem Schäfer. Der Schäfer sieht das aber anders.

Comment: @Shegit read the examples in wiktionary closely. Of course *unter den Nagel reißen* is used with abstract objects (a company for example).

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass viele Schäfer von Wölfen einen Sinn für Fairness überhaupt erwarten. Gemessen an den Möglichkeiten von Schäfern (Schäferhunde, Elektrodraht, Nachtsichtgeräte, Feuerwaffen) kann sich der Schäfer m.E. nicht beschweren. Erfolgreich Beute machen, Jagdverhalten schwingt mit - Unfairness oder Rechtswidrigkeit nicht.

Comment: @vectory: as far as I see I claimed to use *unter den Nagel reißen* for objects and you insist it is used for abstract objects? Gathering possession about a company does not imply becoming CEO. See GmbH, AG, KG, OHG... - all can have owners that are no CEO. I wrote "looks unfair" and the Q write "muss uns reingelegt haben" - where is the disjunction of *looks unfair* and *feeling been taken by him"?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich hätte die Beschreibung nicht für Katze & Maus oder Wolf & Schaf verwendet. Ja, wenn ich weiter denke, ist "Überrumpelung" wohl der bessere Begriff, will change that.

Comment: @userunknown: hinsichtlich Beute-machen: Ich finde, die beiden "reißen"-Redewendungen erfordern sowas wie "Gelegenheit erkennen, die sich lohnt, auch wenn andere mit gleicher Ausgangsposition (hier: Wölfe, Katzen) das übersehen hätten.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that "unter den Nagel reißen" is putting something into your possession while "an sich reißen" is taking control.  The former is more "they bagged something" and the latter is more "they grabbed something".

"Er hat das Projekt an sich gerissen" means that he has grabbed control of a project in-house whereas "Er hat sich das Projekt unter den Nagel gerissen" is something you'd rather say for an outside contractor having bagged a contract you would have wanted.

Your usage of

> Er muss uns reingelegt und sich die Beute selbst unter den Nagel gerissen haben!

is a bit iffy since it implies that he was part of a group making the booty.  It would fit perfectly if a group of thieves hired a guide and the guide made off with the booty instead of (or in addition to) the agreed price.  If he was a member of the group of thieves, you'd say "Er muss uns reingelegt und sich die Beute allein unter den Nagel gerissen haben!".

"Unter den Nagel reißen" carries a connotation of reckless selfishness and exploitative behavior (as does "an sich reißen") but not outright stealing (from the complaining party).  It's more indicative of "I'd have had the same or more right to this" rather than "this was outright theft".

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions are similar. In your example you could use both: **die Beute an sich reißen** and **sich die Beute unter den Nagel reißen**.

In my opinion, **sich unter den Nagel reißen** sounds significantly more negative: You hastily and greedily acquire possession over an object that is free for grabs, even though you are probably neither the most deserving nor the most needy person.

*An sich reißen* has the same connotations, but less strong.
There are cases for **an sich reißen**, for which the other expression can't be used:

- *"Als ich aus dem Bus aussteigen wollte, hatte ich das Gefühl, dass sich jemand an meiner Handtasche zu schaffen machte. Ich riss ich sie sofort näher an mich, damit mir nichts geklaut wird."*
  (No change of possession, simply an abrupt pull movement.)
- *"Er musste stark an sich reißen, um nicht lautstark loszulachen."*

  (Totally different context.)
- *"Sie riss die Gesprächsführung (Verantwortung, Aufgabe,...) an sich."*
  (Note: "sich unter den Nagel reißen" doesn't work, even if the meaning is the same as in your example - apart from being figurative.)

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, both variants of "reissen" have a negative, agressive connotation. However, while "an sich reissen" could also mean an aggressive taking of something (that could either belong to the actor or someone else), the "unter den Nagel reissen" is more of the kind of taking something which does not belong to you.

Comment: Die Bedeutung sich etwas auf aggressive Weise anzueignen muss keineswegs negativ bewertet werden. Im Gegenteil, man verwendet es auch in der ersten Person, ohne es selbstkritisch verstanden wissen zu wollen, etwa: "Gestern hat jemand zwei Beamer in den Ebay-Kleinanzeigen verschenkt - die habe ich mir gleich unter den Nagel gerissen!"

Answer (score 0):

*Sich etwas unter den Nagel reißen* wird eigentlich immer metaphorisch benutzt und man könnte dann auch immer *an sich reißen* sagen. Umgekehrt kann man aber Objekte oder Personen im Wortsinne an sich reißen, etwa den Sohn, während der SUV nur wenige Zentimeter entfernt auf der Landstraße an diesem vorbeizischt. Das könnte man nicht gleichbedeutend mit **unter den Nagel reißen** ausdrücken.

Zwar kann Gier das Motiv des *sich unter den Nagel Reißens*/*an sich Reißens* oft angenommen werden - es kann aber Wachheit, Clevernes, Entscheidungsfreudigkeit, Reaktionsschnelligkeit auch anerkennend ausdrücken.

Comment: If the question is in English, please also answer in English

Comment: Da nicht nur Englischsprachige Fragen zur deutschen Sprache haben plädiere ich eher dafür, die Fragen auf Deutsch zu stellen.

Comment: Also jeder muss auf Deutsch fragen? Das ist doch überhaupt nicht praktikabel. Es soll in der Sprache geantwortet werden, in der gefragt wurde. Ist doch einfach, oder?

Comment: Nicht jeder muss - weder kann ich das alleine bestimmen, noch wollte ich so restriktiv sein. Ich finde aber, jeder sollte es versuchen. Ist doch auch einfach, oder?

Comment: Leider ist dieses Deutsch aber besonders schwer verständlich. Nach "Sohn" fehlt ein Komma. Das würde den Satz aber kaum retten, weil die Adposition "Sohn" dann wie ein Einschub aussehen würde, als wäre "wenn" wieder auf "Objekte" bezogen. Auch: Gemeint ist an der Stelle wohl *Er **rettete** den Sohn an sich*. Ja, *Er krallte sich den Sohn* wäre an der Stelle bspw schon stilistisch fragwürdig -- gutes Bsp zur Abgrenzung müsste nur deutlicher hervorgehoben werden.

Comment: I agree with this answer to the meta post that deals with this exact same question: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1049/30455  furthermore, we are a bilingual site and should respect the (in-)abilities of users who are not proficient enough in either English or German. To my understanding the consensus is to answer in the same language or provide a translation. Therefore I give -1 to this otherwise great answer, until this is resolved.

Comment: @infinitezero: That's not a consensus, as easily to been seen in my habits and argumentation, but just a majority opinion of people, participating in the debate and a self selected subgroup, since the lingua franca on meta is (was?) English, so People, who have problems with English, might have already decided to stay away from meta, leaving people with better English skills alone.

Comment: @vectory: Reichen 706 Reputationspunkte nicht aus, um eine Korrektur vorzunehmen? Korrekturen, die im Sinne des Autors sind, sind immer willkommen. Ich denke bei Sprachthemen auch wg. Kleinigkeiten, im Ggs. zu den Programmierbereichen etc., wo ich auch nicht wegen eines Kommas ein Edit anstoßen würde. Mit "wenn" meinst Du "während", nehme ich an.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense to me, if someone gets his question answered in German but doesn't speak it. It's completely pointless. If you want, I can translate your answer for you so it will become bilingual.

Comment: @infinitezero: Was lässt Dich denken Con-gras-tue-les-chiens spräche kein Deutsch? Mal das Profil angeschaut? Wäre es in meinem Sinne auf Englisch zu antworten würde ich das wohl zur Not auch hinbekommen - sieh dazu meine Profile auf den anderen Seiten (SO, AU, U&L, ...), abgesehen von der Kommasetzung.

Comment: What about other people that reach this question because they searched in English and now can not understand your answer? I really don't understand why you are so much against this.

Comment: Was ist mit Leuten, die kein Englisch können? Wie soll denn jemand, der gar kein Deutsch kann, überhaupt auf die Frage kommen?

Answer (score -1):

For me the difference between **an sich reißen** and **sich unter den Nagel reißen** is in the way in which the object has been taken.
When somebody **etw. an sich reißt** it is obvious for every one.
But when somebody **sich etw. unter den Nagel reißt** it may take some time before the missing object is discovered. And the whole action has been carried out with more secrecy.